# Twitter app traffic not showing in proxy

Tags: twitter, proxy, mitmproxy

I have set up mitmproxy on my ubuntu machine then I installed the mitmproxy certifcate on my android phone and configured my phone to use ubuntu as the default gateway.I used these iptable rules in ubuntu to redirect all traffic to mitmproxy

```
iptables  -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Now I can see all http and https traffic from all apps except twitter.I can see twitter traffic on wireshark but not in mitmproxy.
It just doesn’t make any sense? how twitter traffic bypass mitmproxy to reach the internet?